# Microsoft Excel formula required

Tags: excel

I have a specific data in a column which is like this

```
172s (2m 8s)
150s (2m 30s)
```

I need to remove the  `(xxxm xxs)` from the column. What will be the formula to remove this?

Answer (score 0):

Select the relevant cells.  In the edit menu, select replace.  In "Find What" type in "(*)" - don't include the quotes.  In "Replace With" leave that blank.  This says find all occurrences of open parenthesis with some stuff in the middle and close parenthesis, and replace it with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose 150s (2m 30s)  is in cell `E2`

Then in e.g. F2 you type : `=LEFT(E2;FIND("(";E2)-2)` 
`;` is separation sign, which may have to be replaced by `,`
assuming that the "(" is Always preceded by a space, otherwise use 
as a formula :  `=LEFT(E2;FIND("(";E2)-1)`

In the latter case the resulting string will end with a " " (space)